# Group by error while executing query

Tags: oracle

```
Select To_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'),
       max(decode(fld008,1,count(1),null)) as aa,
       max(decode(fld008,2,count(1),null)) as bb
  From Pti020 x, Pti042 y
 Where x.Fld008 = y.Fld001
   And x.fld004 < trunc(sysdate-1)
   and x.fld004 > trunc(sysdate-2)
 Group By  To_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')
 order by To_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'), aa, bb;
```

Why I am getting 00937 error while executing? How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally don't nest aggregation functions.  Perhaps you intend a query more like this:

```
select To_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24'),
       sum(case when fld008 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as aa,
       sum(case when fld008 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as bb
from Pti020 x join
     Pti042 y
     on x.Fld008 = y.Fld001
where x.fld004 < trunc(sysdate-1) and
      x.fld004 > trunc(sysdate-2)
group By to_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')
order by To_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24');
```

Here are the changes:

- The `,` was replaced by an explicit `JOIN`.  You should use the proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- The aggregation functions count the values of "1" and "2" for the two columns.  If you just want a flag, use `max()` instead of `sum()`.
- I removed the `aa` and `bb` from the `order by` because the `group by` guarantees that the first column is unique.

Comment: I'd also suggest removing `to_char` from both `group by` and `order by` clauses for the sake of performance.

Comment: @DmitryGrekov - it appears OP wants to group by date and hour, so at the very least he'd need `TRUNC(x.FLD004, 'HH24')` in the field list and GROUP BY.

Comment: @BobBravis, yes I was blind. But anyway sorting by `To_char(x.Fld004, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')` doesn't look as reasonable as sorting by date.

Comment: @DmitryGrekov . . . That would not be the same query.  Presumably, the data could have multiple records within a single hour.